# custom managed record and memory leak

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Using Delphi 10.4.1 I tried Custom Managed record management to initialize a record but still get memory leaks.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, System.IOUtils, System.DateUtils, System.Character,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

type
  TMyRec = record
    DateTime: TDateTime;
    v, size: integer;
    str: string;
    class operator Initialize (out Dest: TMyRec);
  end;

  TMyREcHolder = class
    data: TMyRec;
    constructor Create(const e: TMyRec);
  end;

  TMyList = class(TList)
    procedure Clear; override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

class operator TmyRec.Initialize (out Dest: TMyRec);
begin
  Dest.str := '';
end;

{ TMyREcHolder }


constructor TMyREcHolder.Create(const e: TMyRec);
begin
  inherited Create;
  data := e;
end;

{ TMyList }

procedure TMyList.Clear;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    TMyREcHolder(Items[i]).Free;
  inherited Clear;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lst: TMyList;
  i: integer;
  rec: TMyRec;
  FI: TSearchrec;
begin
  Initialize(rec);
  lst := TMyList.Create;
  try
    if FindFirst(TPath.Combine('C:\temp', '*.txt'), faAnyFile, FI) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        if (FI.FindData.dwFileAttributes and faDirectory = 0) and
          (FI.FindData.dwFileAttributes and faArchive = faArchive) then
        begin
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
            0: Initialize(rec);
            1: rec.str := '';
            2: fillchar(rec, sizeof(rec), 0);
          end;
          try
            rec.DateTime := FI.TimeStamp;
          except
            rec.DateTime := EncodeDateDay(1970, 1);
          end;
          rec.size := FI.size;
          rec.str := FI.Name;
          lst.Add(TMyREcHolder.Create(rec));
        end;
      until (FindNext(FI) <> 0);
      FindClose(FI);
    end;
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

The radiogroup offers three items, both 1 and 3 leak memory. Can anyone explain why the Initialize one does? I want a reliable way of clearing a record to help me wean myself off a 20 year fillchar habit.

Comment: Isn't the point of the `Initialize` operator that the compiler calls it for you when the record is created? If you want to clear a record in a loop do `rec := Default(TMyRec)`. Looking at your code I think that you've got the wrong end of the stick with what the `Initialize` operator does. It looks like you believe it can be invoked by you when you like, but, at least as I understand it, it's called by the compiler injecting implicit calls, made when records are created.

Comment: Yes, I just assumed I could use a record function whenever I wanted. Strange that I cannot put into a custom function I can just call (like in a class). I wanted to use a documented operator. I understand Default has been around for a long time but isn't official. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: `Default()` is official. When you call `Initialize(rec)` you aren't calling your operator. You are calling an RTL function. And one that IIRC, you should not call. So I believe that the answer to your question is still that you should use `rec := Default(...)` in place of your `FillChar` calls.

Comment: To elaborate on the RTL function `Initialize()`, it's effectively what is used by the RTL to default initialize managed types in a type that has been allocated on the heap. You shouldn't be calling it, and certainly not for the things described here.

Comment: Another question is What are you trying to achieve here? strings are managed type and they will be automatically initialized in record. Next why are you storing record in TMyREcHolder object? If you are already using classes, you might as well put all fields in class. I would use records with generic list TList<TMyRec> and avoid fiddling with memory management.

Comment: Or I could put a procedure Clear; into my record, to do whatever custom clearing or resetting the various fields need, yes?

Comment: Yes, create and use a Clear procedure. Using FillChar to clear a record is and has always be problematic when any managed type is stored because there is no chance to do the management (Management is done by compiler magic).

Comment: TMyList would benefit from inheriting from generic TList<TMyRecHoler> or even TObjectList<TMyRecHolder>. As Dalija said, you holder class is not needed at all except for other purpose you don't showed us.

Comment: I don't care for a `Clear` method. I'm not a fan an methods that mutate state of value types. I'd far rather use the assignment operator for value types. And `Default()` is perfect for your needs here. If you want initialization other than default (i.e. zero) then I would add a class method named `New` that returned a newly minted instance. So you then have `rec := TMyRec.New(...)`. I often have overloads accepting different arguments.

Comment: I know you can use constructors with records, but I find that confusing because it makes it harder for me to see that these are records and not classes. So I personally opt to keep constructors just for classes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions and comments. They help me learn. I will probably learn to use Generics too but haven't, to date.